# VHost for Subdomain Website

Tags: apache, vhosts

I'm using a Linux Server for my website **www.domain.com**

I want to create the subdomain **www.test.domain.com** for a test environment.

I started configuring the vhost-file.

```
 <Directory /var/www/domain/>
 AllowOverride None
 Order Deny, Allow
 Deny from all
 </Directory>

<VirtualHost *:80>
  DocumentRoot /var/www/domain/

  ServerName domain.com
  ServerAlias domain.com
  ServerAlias www.domain.com
  ServerAdmin support@domain.com

  ErrorLog /var/ww/domain/

<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
</IfModule>

<Directory /var/www/domain/
      Options FollowSymLinks
      AllowOverride All
      Order allow, deny
      Allow from all
</Directory>
```

How can I edit the Vhost file for the subdomain www.test.domain.com in directory ,,/var/www/test/"?

Answer (score 0):

A Sub-Domain is actually a separate domain. You will need to create a new VHost for Sub-Domain.

```
<Directory /var/www/test/>
 AllowOverride None
 Order Deny, Allow
 Deny from all
 </Directory>

<VirtualHost *:80>
  DocumentRoot /var/www/test/

  ServerName test.domain.com
  ServerAlias testdomain.com
  ServerAlias www.test.domain.com
  ServerAdmin support@test.domain.com

  ErrorLog /var/ww/test/

<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
</IfModule>

<Directory /var/www/test/
      Options FollowSymLinks
      AllowOverride All
      Order allow, deny
      Allow from all
</Directory>
```

You can set all your parameters as you like, separately for Sub-Domain.